# ReactJS editable table cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to edit and update single table cell value. I created a function(that returns bunch of options) to be called onClick of that particular cell but onClick of any cell, all the elements in that column are being replaced.

What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/gkLe4qu0/ 
(I am talking about Status column)

```
<tbody>
  {requestsFiltered.map((request, i) =>(
    <tr key={i} className={request.status}>
      <td> {request.title} </td>
      <td onClick={() => this.editStatus(event)}>
        <a id={request.id} data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to edit status">
          {
            this.state.isStatusClicked ? <StatusOptions /> : request.status
          }
        </a>
      </td>
      <td> {request.created_at.format('YYYY-MM-DD')} </td>
      <td> {request.updated_at.format('YYYY-MM-DD')} </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" id={request.id} onClick={() => this.deleteRow(event)}> 
          Delete 
        </a> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Because you are using single state value to keep track whether the status is clicked or not. You need to check for individual items. So, you need an array of booleans where index would be ids of your data and boolean content specifying whether the particular item is clicked or not.

Comment: You can add a state for `selectedStatusId` and check it against `request.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Hardik Modha in comments, you are missing the row level identification, but you can leverage the `map` index to get this working. No need to maintain separate statusId's or so.

```
<tbody>
  {requestsFiltered.map((request, i) =>(
    <tr key={i} className={request.status}>
      <td> {request.title} </td>
      <td onClick={() => this.editStatus(event, i)}>
        <a id={request.id} data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to edit status">
          {
            this.state.isStatusClicked == i ? <StatusOptions /> : request.status
          }
        </a>
      </td>
      <td> {request.created_at.format('YYYY-MM-DD')} </td>
      <td> {request.updated_at.format('YYYY-MM-DD')} </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" id={request.id} onClick={() => this.deleteRow(event)}> 
          Delete 
        </a> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

And also change, `editStatus` to something like:

```
editStatus(event, index){
      console.log("edit status clicket");
      console.log(event.target.id);
      this.setState ({
          isStatusClicked: index
      })
}
```

Refer the changes made: https://jsfiddle.net/nagtan3/gkLe4qu0/4/

You still have to fix the selection of combo box changes:

```
applyStatusChange(event, index) {
    const {value} = event.target;
    let newRequestData = this.state.requests.slice();

    newRequests[index]['status'] = value;
    this.setState ({
      requests: newRequests
    })
}
```

and use the above method as:

```
<tbody>
      {requestsFiltered.map((request, i) =>(
        <tr key={i} className={request.status}>
          <td> {request.title} </td>
          <td onClick={() => this.editStatus(event, i)}>
            <a id={request.id} data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to edit status">
              {
                this.state.isStatusClicked == i ? <StatusOptions onChangeMethod={(event) => applyStatusChange(event, i)} /> : request.status
              }
            </a>
          </td>
          <td> {request.created_at.format('YYYY-MM-DD')} </td>
          <td> {request.updated_at.format('YYYY-MM-DD')} </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#" id={request.id} onClick={() => this.deleteRow(event)}> 
              Delete 
            </a> 
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Welcome :) @SrikanthBandaru